# Google Apps Engine mail fetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail

How can I fetch mails from gmail account  in Google Apps Engine Django application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Configure your app to receive email](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html), then, if it really has to be a gmail address, set up the gmail address to forward everything to your appspot address.

Answer (score 0):

You could cronjob rss feed to gmail messages?

[gmail rss](http://www.forevergeek.com/2004/10/gmail_rss_feed/)

[python cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/) -- seems to be the most popular pure-Python way to do it. However for app engine use I believe it would have to be ported to use urlfetch and I don't think anybody's done that yet (I'd happily receive news to the contrary!-).

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Python's standard [POP](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html) or [IMAP](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) client.  Google does not provide a GMail API.

Comment: You can't open sockets on App Engine.

Comment: Maybe he just did not know better. Sometimes I think the down votting is kind of cruel

Comment: No problem, because I understand when somebody is really posting dumb stuff about php instead of python or flaming that he gets down voted. But this..?

Comment: @Alfred - it is a bad answer based on a reasonable misunderstanding. I think other people might try the approach I suggested, but it won't work for the reason Nick Johnson cited. In my opinion it should be downvoted once and left as a warning. I only have issue when innocently wrong answers are downvoted multiple times.